# Is it common practice to use brackets just on the wall to install a fixed shower glass panel?

Tags: shower, glass

This morning they took the measurement for the glass panels that I need for my shower, they will be 78x32 and 78x36.

The guy who took the measurements wanted just two brackets on the wall for each panel and he wanted to use just silicone on the floor. I did not like that and I asked for brackets at the bottom and he is telling me that one bracket on the floor (shower base) should be enough.

Is it common practice not to put brackets on the bottom side? I asked for a frameless setup.

Comment: At my recent stay at a resort in Cancun, the shower surround had brackets on the walls, but the glass went to the floor and was silicone sealed.

Comment: Unless you plan on kicking the panel, silicon will do a good job of holding it to the floor.  Even with kicking, the brackets might give before the silicon.

Comment: Won't that look bad as it ages?
I mean I am looking at the silicon around my bath tub and it looks awful after a couple of years it seems it is like aging

Comment: It depends.  Years ago(10 or 20), I replaced a window pane in a external door.  Was not cleaned up perfectly and the silicon I can see is as clear as when it was used.  The paint on the door should have been redone some time ago.